# How to add a comment to your blog

Tags: discussion

I've found several sources relating to the question on this page :
[Where can I find official documents of Buenos Aires' Eucharistic Miracle?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/where-can-i-find-official-documents-of-buenos-aires-eucharistic-miracle)
How can I add a comment (does not work) ?

Comment: [As explained here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), you need 50 reputation to post comments on other people's posts.